# TestExecute run on the virtual machine?

Tags: automation, testcomplete

Can i run the TestExecute on virtual machine? Or testexecute required the display device to execute the tests? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, TestExecute needs UI of Windows and the tested application be visible to run test that interacts with this UI. You can find information on how to deal with this situation in the [Running Tests on Locked Computers](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/74665/) article.